# MySQL Select where column based on IF

Tags: mysql

Here's my database structure (simplified) :

```
Subscriptions (id, day, user_id)
MagazineEvents(id, magazine_id, subscription_id, ..., is_even_week, is_odd_week)
Magazine(id, name, ...)
```

The magazines can be out when week_number%2 == 0 (even) or == 1 (odd), but also every week (even & odd at 1) or never (even & odd at 0).

I need to list the correct magazines of each subscribers, so here what I did :

```
SELECT s.* FROM Subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN MagazineEvents me ON me.subscription_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN Magazine p ON m.id = me.magazine_id
WHERE ...
```

The `WHERE` is where I'm stuck, i need to to return one or no magazine based on the day of the subscription, I have the `SQL` for getting the week modulo : `DATE_FORMAT(day, "%v") % 2`, but that's it, I can't go any further.

Answer (score 1):

use case when ladder 
like

```
CASE when (DATE_FORMAT(day, "%v") % 2) = 0 then 'even' else 'odd' end
```

in query

Comment: Interesting, and instead of 'even' and 'odd', I just have to make the column check here : `THEN is_even_week = 1 ELSE is_odd_week = 1` ! Perfect